# Single-pass run of Clang tools (clang-tidy, iwyu, etc.) along with compilation?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang-tidy, iwyu

Is there a feasible way to run Clang's various code-checking tools (like clang-tidy and include-what-you-use) together with compilation, so that the source code is only parsed and processed *once* (single-pass)?

I'm doing this to help compilation performance, since parsing C++ is quite a nontrivial and expensive process.

Comment: You may find [ccache](https://ccache.dev/) useful.